# Dropwizard Multiple Asset Bundles Conflict

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have a couple of different single page applications to embed in a single dropwizard process.  If I register more than one bundle, only the last bundle wins.

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/web1", "/web1", "index.html));
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/web2", "/web2", "index.html));
```

Only web2 is served.  If I reverse these lines, only web1 is served.

How do I properly configure dropwizard so that both are served?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try naming those bundles differently:

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/web1", "/web1", "index.html, "asset1"));
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/web2", "/web2", "index.html, "asset2"));
```

Implementation of the AssetsBundle constructor you're using is as:

```
public AssetsBundle(String resourcePath, String uriPath, String indexFile) {
    this(resourcePath, uriPath, indexFile, "assets");
}
```

Hence your asset bundle gets overriden by the latter configuration. This was solved in a similar manner 
in [`dropwizard#499`](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/499).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @nullpointer!  Indeed even the docs cover it here:

http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.1/docs/manual/core.html

When an AssetBundle is added to the application, it is registered as a servlet using a default name of assets. If the application needs to have multiple AssetBundle instances, the extended constructor should be used to specify a unique name for the AssetBundle.

The fix is to use that 4th parameter as you pointed out.

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/web1", "/web1", "index.html, "asset1"));
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/web2", "/web2", "index.html, "asset2"));
```